# Send secret key to API

Tags: php, api, curl, laravel-5

My API have AUTH_KEY in .env file. I want to check this KEY trough middleware. 
I send all my requests to API(another domain) with cURL. And I can't understand how I can send this Key with every request.

Especially, how can I check it. I found some way to send it:

```
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'AUTH_KEY: secret'
    ));
```

I didn't know work it or not, because I don't understand how to get access to this Variable?

UPD. Its my own API) There is now instructions how to send it)

Here is my Request.php

```
class Request
{
//Return Array of objects with parameters 'id', 'name'
public static function sendRequest($request_type, $url, $param = null)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "backend_service.com/api/$url");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'AUTH_KEY: secret'
    ));
    switch ($request_type) {
        case "GET":
            $server_output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
            break;
        case "POST":
            $query = http_build_query(array(
                    "name" => $param->name,
                    "description" => $param->description,
                    "category_id" => 2,
                    "type_id" => 3)
            );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
            $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            $query = http_build_query(array(
                    "name" => $param->name,
                    "description" => $param->description,
                    "category_id" => $param->category_id,
                    "type_id" => $param->type_id)
            );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request_type);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
            $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request_type);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
            $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
            break;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $server_output;
  }
}
```

Comment: The 3rd party API should normally have instructions on how it expects to receive the key

Comment: Well that depends how you're building or sending your requests, which we don't know.

Comment: Useful comment, Lawrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following on the API end:

```
<?php

$auth = isset(getallheaders()['AUTH_KEY']) ? getallheaders()['AUTH_KEY'] : '';
var_dump($auth);
```

It will provide you the header parameter `AUTH_KEY`. for more info [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)

Comment: Can I ask one more question here, please? Why I can't get access to AUTH_KEY like this, when I make ajax request. I'm sending Header via Ajax.

Comment: @NikitaYunoshev I just tried and it works, copy the code from here and check with that: https://eval.in/873536

Comment: I put my comment here - eval.in/873554. Too much text. Check please, if you can

Comment: @NikitaYunoshev inside headers there is no `"` before `AUTH_KEY` check that.

Comment: I'm missed it just in "eval.in". In my code everything correct(

Comment: @NikitaYunoshev I am not sure try looking into chrome devtools' `network` tab to see wether the headers are being sent or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155934/discussion-between-nikita-yunoshev-and-mega6382).